# How to flatten properties inside json array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried some code to flatten but it flattens the whole json. My requirement is just to flatten only position property.

I have following json array:

```
[{
amount:"1 teine med 110 mtr iletau"
comment:""
created:"Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
locationDescription:"På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden)."
position:{lat: 59.441388, lng: 10.579491}
time:"15-05-2016"
type:"Teine"
userId:""
},
{
amount:"1 teine med 110 mtr iletau"
comment:""
created:"Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
locationDescription:"På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden)."
position:{lat: 59.441388, lng: 10.579491}
time:"15-05-2016"
type:"Teine"
userId:""
}]
```

I want output like:

```
[{
amount:"1 teine med 110 mtr iletau"
comment:""
created:"Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
locationDescription:"På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden)."
position.lat:59.441388, 
position.lng: 10.579491,
time:"15-05-2016"
type:"Teine"
userId:""
},
{
amount:"1 teine med 110 mtr iletau"
comment:""
created:"Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
locationDescription:"På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden)."
position.lat: 59.441388, 
position.lng: 10.579491,
time:"15-05-2016"
type:"Teine"
userId:""
}]
```

Can someone suggests me how to achieve the above output in javascript ?

Comment: Umm... The second JSON is not a valid JSON. `:(`

Comment: `position.lat : 59.441388` is invalid. It could be `"position.lat" : 59.441388`, is that what you want?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The original version of the object (a JavaScript object, not a "JSON object") allows you to reference the `position` sub-properties as `array[n].position.lat` and `array[n].position.lng` as it is. Your desired result makes that less convenient.

Comment: I am using file-saver.js for exporting json array to excel. It works fine with flat json. But If i use above json then it exports position column as blank. So I need position.lat , position.lng

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the array and build new properties and delete `position.`

```js
var array = [{ amount: "1 teine med 110 mtr iletau", comment: "", created: "Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)", locationDescription: "På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden).", position: { lat: 59.441388, lng: 10.579491 }, time: "15-05-2016", type: "Teine", userId: "" }, { amount: "1 teine med 110 mtr iletau", comment: "", created: "Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)", locationDescription: "På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden).", position: { lat: 59.441388, lng: 10.579491 }, time: "15-05-2016", type: "Teine", userId: "" }];

array.forEach(o => {
    Object.assign(o, { 'position.lat': o.position.lat, 'position.lng': o.position.lng });
    delete o.position;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a flexible solution, you can use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).  Notice that the function calls itself to traverse the object:

```
$ cat test.js && echo "\n-------\n" && node test.js
const subject = {a:1, b:2, c:{d:3, e:{f:4, g:5}}};

function flatten (obj){
  const result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      const flattened = flatten(value);
      Object.keys(flattened).forEach( subKey => {
         result[`${key}.${subKey}`] = flattened[subKey]
      })
    } else {
      result[key] = value
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(flatten(subject), null, 2));

-------

{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c.d": 3,
  "c.e.f": 4,
  "c.e.g": 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or using Array.map()

```js
const arr = [
{
  amount:"1 teine med 110 mtr iletau",
  comment:"",
  created:"Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)",
  locationDescription:"På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss. (Oslofjorden).",
  position:{lat: 59.441388, lng: 10.579491},
  time:"15-05-2016",
  type:"Teine",
  userId:""
},
{
  amount:"1 teine med 110 mtr iletau",
  comment:"",
  created:"Tue May 17 2016 00:00:00 (W. Europe Standard Time)",
  locationDescription:"På vestsiden av Jeløya, utenfor Moss.(Oslofjorden).",
  position:{lat: 59.441388, lng: 10.579491},
  time:"15-05-2016",
  type:"Teine",
  userId:""
}
];


const flattenPositions = o => {
  o["position.lng"] = o.position.lng;
  o["position.lat"] =  o.position.lat;
  delete o.position;
  return o;
 };

arr = arr.map(el=>flattenPositions(el));


console.log(arr);
```

Comment: you still mutate the original object.

Comment: you're right to mention that! (however that's what the op wants. But no needs for a new declaration, you're right)

Comment: By the way, I often read your answers (and learn a lot from them), so why iterations today vs map?

Comment: was it a question to me? if so, i wrote, that map does not work because of the switched array. the outer array reflects the result's inner array and vice versa. given 15 x 4 wanted 4 x 15.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your time.